# How to remove opacity only for a particular div or class

Tags: html, css

This is my site: http://vani.valse.com.my/schone_lightings/index.php

I set transparency for the class row as below:

```
.row

{
   max-width: 85%;


   background-color:#fff;

   opacity:0.95;

   filter:alpha(opacity=95)


}
```

It's working fine,just that I don't want opacity applied for mobile offcanvas menu. I'm using Zurb foundation bytheway. If you resize the browser to mobile size ,you can see the offcanvas menu. When scrolled down you may see, the content scrolls through the sticky bar. I dont want that to happen Long story short just this offcanvas class, I want to remove the opacity. Is it possible?

Secondly , need to push the content for the mobile version little bit down as the sticky bar overlays it.

Thanks in advance experts!!!

Comment: You should take a look at medias queries, they let you choose what happen when size of your screen change. Here is a quick example : in your css file, write `@media all and (max-width : 420px) { .row { opacity : 1; } }`. This last remove the opacity when the screen is below 421px.

Comment: For your first problem see @zertops, for the second problem add padding/margin for the smaller layout using media query.

Comment: @Zeratops can u help me to fix this issue where all the links in pages become unclickable when I enabled the offcanvas menu. I thougt it something to do with z-index but not working.

Comment: I just checked for your issue but it seems to be quite complicated since I cannot access the exact code. I don't think it is something interesting but, when I checked for the code inspector with FireFox, it seems the checkbox are enabled (I see my cusor becoming `pointer`).

Comment: @Zeratops thank u so much.I finally fixed it. Just need to remove height:100% from off-canvas  fixed class.

Answer (score 0):

Add 1 `blank class (ex: removeOpacity)` next to `row class` where your `offcanvas menu` is there. And in css at the bottom or any place add your `media queries` as below depend on width you want.

```
@media all and (max-width : 420px) { .removeOpacity { opacity : 1; } }
```

It will remove your opacity.

And same way add `blank class` where you want to push your text little down. And with the help of `media queries` give padding or margin to that container or div.

Comment: If she doesn't want to add any other class, `.removeOpacity` is useless, since she only have `.row` class. You can still "overide" `.row` when using media queries. Your solution needs to add `.removeOpacity` dynamically, and remove `.row` to effects.

Comment: On her page there is multiple `.row` class and she wont to remove `opacity` of `offcanvas menu` not every1. Read her question properly.